# User was removed

Tags: discussion

A quick question:

I received a notification on my reputation log with a -10 and the caption saying "User was removed" several hours before I answered a question and received positive reputation.  I couldn't find a definition in the Help Section nor has this question seem to have come up before.

Can anyone clarify the meaning of this term?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a user was removed, but you had some upvotes from him, you will lose those votes.

There is no direct information as to which user was removed, but you could work it out if you want to.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: I want to! How can it be worked out? And why should it not be readily available?